# How to pass variables from Node.JS back end to front end Javascript without exposing what the data contains

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

This question's answer shows how to do what I'm doing currently:

[How to pass variable from back-end to front-end in node.js ejs template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23733748/how-to-pass-variable-from-back-end-to-front-end-in-node-js-ejs-template)

I'm passing the variable into the EJS render call, then using `JSON.stringify()` to convert it into a format that front-end code can use.

**However is there a way to pass the data to the front-end code that doesn't expose what the data actually contains?**

For a specific example, say I have an API key for something like MapBox that I'm sending into the EJS render as `process.env.MAPBOX_KEY`

When I use the `JSON.stringify()` it exposes that key as plain text for anyone who wants to inspect the page.

I would be grateful if there was a way to get something like that into the front end code in a way that no one can see what it is.

Comment: A user with a browser will always be able to see the payloads of your requests and responses, and your app's cookies.  The Network tab of devtools shows those things in a nice convenient format. So, secrets that you can't trust your legitimate users to know cannot be sent to browsers.

Comment: Huh, hadn't thought of that. So in the case of the MapBox example, would it be better to have a function on the back end which generates the HTML for the map, then send that into the EJS template?

Comment: With Mapbox, you can get yourself a token with a URL restriction. Mapbox insists that all requests come from pages matching your URL restriction. That's the way to secure those tokens. Other than that, don't worry about it. Mapbox offers a public token, so it seems they don't mind people "borrowing" it.